# Как отслеживать запущенный процесс с помощью Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, процесс

Мне необходимо найти необходимый мне процесс, например калькулятор. Процесс должен быть запущен пользователем, а не программой! То есть мне не нужно создавать процесс. Мне просто нужно найти его в списке всех запущенных процессов. Мне не надо использовать WMI, а также winapi, мне надо это реализовать на Qt, в заранее спасибо.

Comment: qt кроссплатформенный фреймворк. с его помощью вы это сделать не сможете

Comment: из коробки в Qt AFAIK ничего подобного нет... можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, а можно накатать свою реализацию на системно-зависимых API.

Comment: хорошо, я понял, а есть какие-то у вас примеры сторонних библиотек?

Comment: [первая ссылку](https://github.com/baldurk/qprocessinfo) в гугле по запросу «qt list of processes»...

Comment: я просил без использования winapi...

Comment: @S1NGer-iwni-, это какая-то принципиальная позиция? если нужна поддержка ОС windows, то код на winapi конечно можно завернуть в несколько слоёв абстракции, но так или иначе на каком-то уровне придётся его использовать (если не прибегать к каким-то абсурдным «хакерским» решениям)...